# Unable to set background color when I click on menu(navigation horizontal) showing the currect menu selected

Tags: html, css

```
   .unorder_Hnav,li,.classes:active
   {
    background-color:#7CA738;
    height: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1024px;  
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 52px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #457025;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here I have used un ordered list, lists(without a class) and finally a href of class (Classes):active.

Now I want to make this properties to get only active, when i click on them and they are suppose to retain it as long as i don't click on any other link. Is there possibility to do using css? Or I need to use jquery only?

Comment: in your title, do you mean _current_ or _correct_?

Answer (score 0):

this part is repeated: is it by mistake ?

here:

```
background-color:#7CA738;
```

then here:

```
background-color: #457025;
```

Comment: That was the mistake while copying code and trying out but still it doesn't active to background color (#457025), when i click on it. It gets back to previous background color(#7CA738), which I have set it before getting clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The `:active` pseudo-class is a means to provide feedback to the user on what they have "activated".  It isn't meant to keep the element in an "active" state.

You can easily create a css class, let's call it `selected` with the definition of it as follows:

```
.selected{
    background-color: #999;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Now you can listen with javascript and remove the class `selected` from the other elements that have it assigned and then assign the `selected` class to the right element.  If this causes navigation, the server can render this element with the `selected` class when rendering the page to get the same effect.

For more information about the `:active` pseudo-class, you can look at [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aactive).